# Unable to see logs in React Native regardless of what I do

Tags: android, react-native, logging

Junior developer here, so sorry if I leave out information that could help. I recently inherited a Bare React-Native project that (I am on windows) we are gutting to reformat into a similar application. One thing I was not able to get working early was any sort of useful logging. I can open the developer tools, but regardless of what I try the only message in the devtools is `Console was cleared`. It will not progress past the splash screen while the devtools are open no matter what I try, and googling has turned up nothing useful. In the past, when I developed with expo, logs just showed up in the terminal where metro was running, and I had no need for the devtools. In the initial gutting of the app, logging was not very necessary because removing something important caused an actual crash. Now I am having state issues and cannot debug.

What I've tried:

1. the integrated VSCode terminal
2. devtools in debug mode
3. opening up a separate terminal and running `react-native log-android`
4. opening up a separate terminal and running `adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V`
5. downloading an external logging tool such as flipper.

The bottom three all produce actual device logs when attached (AKA, navigating through screens gives me logs about reanimated and tearing down screens), but console.logs, console.warns, console.error on buttons do not appear in any form of logging.

If any additional information could help, just let me know. Kind of out of my depth here.

```
Windows 11
Node v18.14.2
React-Native 0.64.1
React-Native-Bootsplash 3.2.7
React-Native-Reanimated 2.17.0
```

Comment: check the bundler , log should appear there if the event where the log is mentioned is triggered , also you could check with flipper

Comment: Did you use react-navigation with an Drawer?

Comment: There are no logs in the bundler.

We did not use a drawer navigator.

Answer (score 0):

React Native app console logs typically manifest within the Metro environment.

When running your app on an iOS simulator via the VSCode terminal, the logs will be visible within Metro. Similarly, when using Xcode to run your app on an iOS simulator, the logs will be accessible in both the Xcode output section and Metro.

In case logs are not appearing for the iOS scenario, one possibility is that your app is running in release mode. However, even in this situation, logs will still appear in the Xcode output section when the app is launched via Xcode.

For Android, when employing the VSCode terminal to run your app on an Android emulator, logs will be visible in Metro. Alternatively, when using Android Studio to run the app on an Android emulator, logs will appear in both the Android Studio RUN section and Metro.

If logs are absent in the Android case, it may indicate an improper connection between your device/emulator and Metro. To verify connectivity, you can press 'R' in Metro. If the app reloads, it's connected; if not, and Metro displays 'reloading app,' then the app isn't connected. To establish a connection, shake your device, access developer options, select 'change bundle location,' and ensure both your PC and device are connected to the same Wi-Fi source. Enter your IP address and port number (8081) in the prompt, and the Metro connection will establish, enabling console log viewing.

To access developer tools on an Android emulator, use the command `adb shell input keyevent 82` in the Android Studio terminal. On an iOS simulator, click the simulator, find the 'Device' option in the taskbar, select `shake` from the menu, and open the developer tool.

Should any of these cases apply to your situation, you can attempt the corresponding solution. If not, kindly provide more details, such as the devices used, and whether the app is in debug or release mode."

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. As I am on Windows, I am not working on the iOS portion of the application, only the android (I cannot run XCode on windows locally). The application is in development mode. When turning on debug mode, the app freezes at the splash screen and will not proceed. There are no messages about a crash in the app, and obviously I cannot check logging to ensure that there are no errors related to debug mode. It would appear that I am connected to metro, as I can reload the app manually and the browser console opens when in debug mode. Its just empty.

Comment: If the app is stuck on the splash screen then there should be an error regarding native modules or libraries, you can check the error in the android studio logcat section